# Coq execution difference between semicolon ";" and period "."

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Given a valid Coq proof using the `;` tactical, is there a general formula for converting it to a valid equivalent proof with `.` substituted for `;`?

Many Coq proofs use the `;` or tactic sequencing tactical. As a beginner, I want to watch the individual steps execute, so I want to substitute `.` for `;`, but to my surprise I find that this may break the proof.

Documentation on `;` is sparse, and I haven't found an explicit discussion of `.` anywhere. I did see a [paper](http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~mabi/papers/PPDP13.pdf) that says informal meaning of `t1; t2` is

> apply `t2` to every subgoal produced by the execution of `t1` in the current proof context,

and I wonder if `.` only operates on the current subgoal and that explains the different behavior?  But especially I want to know if there is a general solution to repairing the breakage caused by substituting `.` for `;`.

Answer (score 18):

The semantics of `tac1 ; tac2` is to run `tac1` and then run `tac2` on *all* the subgoals created by `tac1`. So you may face a variety of cases:

#### There are no goals left after running `tac1`

If there are no goals left after running `tac1` then `tac2` is never run and Coq simply silently succeeds. For instance, in this first derivation we have a useless `; intros` at the end of the (valid) proof:

```
Goal forall (A : Prop), A -> (A /\ A /\ A /\ A /\ A).
intros ; repeat split ; assumption ; intros.
Qed.
```

If we isolate it, then we get an `Error: No such goal.` because we are trying to run a tactics when there is nothing to prove!

```
Goal forall (A : Prop), A -> (A /\ A /\ A /\ A /\ A).
intros ; repeat split ; assumption.
intros. (* Error! *)
```

#### There is exactly one goal left after running `tac1`.

If there is precisely one goal left after running `tac1` then `tac1 ; tac2` behaves a bit like `tac1. tac2`. The main difference is that if `tac2` fails then so does the whole of `tac1 ; tac2` because the sequence of two tactics is seen as a unit that can either succeed as a whole or fail as a whole. But if `tac2` succeeds, then it's pretty much equivalent.

E.g. the following proof is a valid one:

```
Goal forall (A : Prop), A -> (A /\ A /\ A /\ A /\ A).
intros.
repeat split ; assumption.
Qed.
```

#### Running `tac1` generates more than one goal.

Finally, if multiple goals are generated by running `tac1` then `tac2` is applied to all of the generated subgoals. In our running example, we can observe that if we cut off the sequence of tactics after `repeat split` then we have 5 goals on our hands. Which means that we need to copy / paste `assumption` five times to replicate the proof given earlier using `;`:

```
Goal forall (A : Prop), A -> (A /\ A /\ A /\ A /\ A).
intros ; repeat split.
 assumption.
 assumption.
 assumption.
 assumption.
 assumption.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you for the case breakdown!  This helps a lot.

Comment: @ChristopherBrinkley It this post answers your question, it'd be nice if you checked it as *the* answer.

Comment: I'll point out that probably the most *important* difference, aside from applying the tactic in every branch, is that Coq will backtrack through `;`. E.g. even if `tac1` only ever generates one goal, if there are multiple ways for it to do so (an important example would be `constructor`), then `tac1. tac2` will commit to the first success and run `tac2` on it. `tac1; tac2` will make `tac1` try one thing, then try `tac2` after that, and if that fails try `tac1` another way, and then try `tac2` after that, and if that fails try `tac1` *another* another way, etc.