# Why does a proof with semicolons not work with periods?

Tags: syntax, coq

The following proof is given in *Coq in a Hurry*:

```
Fixpoint add n m := match n with 0 => m | S p => add p (S m) end.
Lemma exercise6 : forall n m, add n (S m) = S (add n m).
Proof.
  induction n; intros m; simpl.
    reflexivity.
  rewrite IHn; reflexivity.
Qed.
```

I tried writing this step by step to understand what was happening, but the inductive hypothesis isn't the same after solving the base case! Therefore, the tactics fail:

```
Lemma exercise6' : forall n m, add n (S m) = S (add n m).
Proof.
  induction n.
  intros m.
  simpl.
  reflexivity.
  rewrite IHn. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

They fail at the line staring with "rewrite", with the following error:

> Error: Found no subterm matching `add n (S ?M1580)` in the current goal.

Why does the same code fail when written step-by-step? What is the difference between the semicolon and period?

Furthermore, is there a way I can view the step-by-step progression of the proof given in *Coq in a Hurry*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292552/coq-execution-difference-between-and/36296096#36296096).

In short:

- `induction n` generates 2 subgoals.
- `A;B` applies the tactics `B` to *all* the subgoals generated by `A`

So here, `intros m; simpl` is applied to the 2 goals generated by `induction`. Which means that you can fix your second script by inserting an extra `intros m` and an extra `simpl` before the `rewrite`:

```
Lemma exercise6' : forall n m, add n (S m) = S (add n m).
Proof.
  induction n.
  intros m.
  simpl.
  reflexivity.
  intros m.
  simpl.
  rewrite IHn.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

By the way, you can make the structure of the proof script a lot clearer by using bullets to delimit the various subgoals. This gives the following two scripts where you can see that in `exercise6` the `intros m; simpl` is performed *before* entering either subgoal whereas in `exercise6'` they have been pushed into each subgoal:

```
Lemma exercise6 : forall n m, add n (S m) = S (add n m).
Proof.
  induction n; intros m; simpl.
  - reflexivity.
  - rewrite IHn; reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma exercise6' : forall n m, add n (S m) = S (add n m).
Proof.
  induction n.
  - intros m.
    simpl.
    reflexivity.
  - intros m.
    simpl.
    rewrite IHn.
    reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that! I guess when I searched for the terms "semicolon" and "period", it didn't come up because that answer has ";" and "." in the name. Thanks for your quick answer! I especially appreciate the tip about bullet points - I was wondering how to write more readable code.

Comment: No bother! I've edited the other questions to add semicolon and period to the title. Hopefully it'll make it easier to discover in the future!